# No notification that an application is starting with Ubuntu 14.04. It's normal?

Tags: 14.04, notification

I'm a newbie of Ubuntu after using OpenSuse for many years.

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop PC and I've noticed an annoying problem: there is no notification that an application is starting after clicking on the application icon. It's a normal behaviour???

In OpenSuse (KDE 4) usually the mouse pointer starts bouncing or blinking to inform the user that the application is currently starting. In Ubuntu nothing happens until the application window appears on the screen.

I've also tried other desktop manager than Unity, like gnome-flashback and Cinnamon, but the problem is still there.

Any clue? :(

Comment: If you open an application from the Dash (start menu) then nothing happens, although if you open one from the Launcher the icon in the launcher will glow. Both of these are default behaviors in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

In **Xubuntu** the mouse pointer usually becomes a rotating ball when an application window has just apeared, until all the components ang graphics are loaded. For me this happens when I start **nautilus**.

Comment: I assume you mean Launcher Icon, not the "mouse pointer"

Comment: I meant mouse pointer, but I edited the answer to be more exact what I describe. Thanks for pointed.

Comment: Yeah, even in Windows 95 there was an hourglass... in the first Macintosh the mouse pointer became a watch (if I remember right). In Ubuntu I see nothing... the triumph of minimalism??? :(

I have a quite powerful PC, but I think the problem it's quite annoying for people with a slower computer...

Comment: @gimpo May be annoying, but this is a minor problem if one clicks just once an application icon or a menu item and then waits. If the package is not properly installed/launched then it becomes confusing...

Comment: @vasilis74
sometimes I double-click on a desktop icon two or three times 'cause I don't know if the application has started or not. As result I have two or three windows opening on the screen. So frustrating.... :( :( :(